# probleme with android in kotlin to communication with USB

Tags: android, kotlin, usb

I am trying to communicate between my android and a USB. I followed the instructions from android.com but my smartphone do not ask the authorization to communicate with the USB. However my smartphone do detect when I put a USB or not.In fact the variable "device" is always null and I do not understand why. Do you have an idea of the problem ?

```
var ACTION_USB_ATTACHED :String = “android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED” 
var ACTION_USB_DETACHED :String = “android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED” 
var ACTION_USB_PERMISSION :String = “com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION”

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    var switch_on_off :Switch? = null
    var tv_info : TextView? = null

    //USB
    var mUsbReceiver :UsbReceiver? = null
    var mfilter :IntentFilter? = null
    var mUsbManager :UsbManager? = null
    var mPermissionIntent : PendingIntent? = null
    var device :UsbDevice? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        tv_info = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
        switch_on_off = findViewById<Switch>(R.id.switch1)
        switch_on_off!!.setChecked(false)
        switch_on_off!!.setText("OFF")

        //USB
        mUsbReceiver = UsbReceiver()
        mfilter = IntentFilter()
        mfilter!!.addAction(ACTION_USB_ATTACHED)
        mfilter!!.addAction(ACTION_USB_DETACHED)
        registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, mfilter) 
        mUsbManager = getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE) as UsbManager

        //threads
        t_switchOnOff.start()
    }
    val t_switchOnOff = thread(start = false, priority = 10)
    {
        while(true){
            Thread.sleep(300)
            this@MainActivity.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable {
                if(switch_on_off!!.isChecked()){
                    switch_on_off!!.setText("ON")
                    device = intent?.getParcelableExtra<UsbDevice>(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE) 
                    if(device != null) 
                    {
                        if(!mUsbManager!!.hasPermission(device)){
                            mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
                            mUsbManager!!.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);
                        }
                        else{
                            tv_info!!.setText("")
                            tv_info!!.setText("device USB detected : ${device!!.deviceName} \n
                                & Authorization accorded")
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        tv_info!!.setText("device USB NOT detected \n& usb Detached")
                    }
                }
                else{
                    tv_info!!.setText("")
                    switch_on_off!!.setText("OFF")
                }
            })//end this@MainActivity.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable ...
        }
    }//end thread

    class UsbReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) { 
            val action = intent?.action
            var ACTION_USB_PERMISSION :String = "com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION"
            if (action!!.equals(ACTION_USB_DETACHED)) {}
            if (action!!.equals(ACTION_USB_ATTACHED)){}
            if (action!!.equals(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION)){
                if (!intent!!.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED,false)) {
                    //Authoization refused
                } else {
                    //Authorization accepted
                }
            }
        }
    }//end class UsbReceiver }
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: The first thing i do when I have a device not found issue is run "adb devices" from the command line or where ever adb is.

Answer (score 1):

You actually have to ask permission for each USB device available, something the official Android documentation doesn't really accentuate.

```
// register the broadcast receiver
val manager = getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE) as UsbManager
val permissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0)
val filter = IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION)
registerReceiver(usbReceiver, filter)

for (dev in manager.deviceList)
{
    // returns hashmap<String, UsbDevice>
    Log.i("TAG", dev.key + " " + dev.value)
    // now ask for permission
    manager.requestPermission(dev.value, permissionIntent)
}
```